# How to place components under another component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have React app, where I have page with posts. And I need that post were located to the right of the previous post and in `css` I wrote `float:left`. And my posts are located as needed. But in return my component `Home`  after the component `DisplayPost` I have component `AddPost` and `DeletePost`.And they are located to the right of the posts(to the right of the component `DisplayPost`).

#### But I need that this components were located under the component `DisplayPost`.

How to implement it?

### component Home:

```
return (
      <div>
        <DisplayPost dataAttribute={value.listImage} />
        <AddPost />
        <DeletePost />
      </div>
  );
};
```

### component DisplayPost:

```
export default (props) => {

 return (
   <div>
     {props.dataAttribute.map(item => (
        <div className="galery">
            <div>name: {item.title}</div>
            <div>category: {item.category.title}</div>
            <div><img src={`${apiUrl}uploads/${item.img.filename}`}/></div>
            <div>description: {item.description}</div>
        </div>
      ))}
   </div>
  );
}
```

### style:

```
.galery {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear. But usually, there is no need to use `float` these days but `flex` or `grid`

Comment: This is a `CSS` question rather than `React` question.

Comment: @Mosh Feu  How to write it with flex?

Comment: Well, you got some answers :)

Answer (score 0):

it is related to your css, if you use grid or flex to structure your page :
in the root component :

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column
```

if grid :

```
display: grid
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.galery {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    display :flex;
   flex-wrap  : wrap;
}
```

use flex-wrap this will automatically adjust your div .